# Debian not saving user's preferences of any program

Tags: debian, cache, privileges

Since I did a fresh installation of Debian, my computer is not saving user's preferences. The preferences only are saved for the session, but if I close the program and reopen it, it ask me again the passwords. And for that, I mean:
 - MySQL Workbench ask me every time to put the password for every connection.
 - NetBeans ask me every time to put the password of my remote connections.
An I could say more programs but right now I can't recall.

Any ideas?

SETUP: Debian Jessie 8 / Cinnamon as a desktop manager / Enough free HDD and RAM / Fresh installation a month ago